# Is it normal for Starfleet to provide replacement ships?

Tags: star-trek

I was reading a *Star Trek* post here, and was reminded of an oddity. When Kirk lost the Enterprise, Starfleet gave him and his crew a shiny new Enterprise A. When Picard lost the Enterprise D, something similar happened and he and his crew got a shiny new Enterprise E. When Sisko and crew lost the Defiant, a replacement was provided to them as well, but they didn't tack a letter on to it.

This seems really peculiar to me, as I'd think the loss of a ship would definitely not result in the replacement for that ship being handed right back to the people who necessitated the replacement. But, here are three notable examples.

Is this normal Starfleet/Federation procedure; to grant survivors of a lost ship a replacement?

Comment: You gotta' replace them when the ash trays get full.  I mean, what are you gonna' do, use the transporter to flush that crap into space? There's probably some Federation rule against that.  ;)

Comment: Maybe it was a courtesy ship.

Comment: Starfleet never gave Picard a new Stargazer

Comment: Kirk saved Earth, which probably counted in his favour. Picard in Generations saved an inhabited planet and in Nemesis saved Earth, so the same excuse applies. And the Defiant was lost in the war, and given that humans could not be replicated it was certainly easier to provide a new ship than to find a new captain.

Comment: IRL, in WWII captains who lost their ships in enemy engagements would regularly be reposted. Captains who destroyed their own vessels through incompetence (grounding them or accidentally ramming something) would generally get benched

Comment: @Richard, this would probably not apply to Captains who stole their ship before they lost in any enemy engagement (so a major threat to earth was possibly a lucky escape for Kirk).

Comment: @EikePierstorff though technically picard didn't get a new enterprise after nemesis, i believe they just rebuilt the existing ship. because i believe you see them on a shiny fixed E at the end of the movie.

Comment: @Himarm - Not according to [Ronald Moore](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28NCC-1701-E%29); "*My working assumption was that the Enterprise-E had her keel laid sometime during TNG's last season and was probably going to be given another name. When the Enterprise-D was destroyed, that Sovereign-class ship was nearing completion and was then christened Enterprise.*"

Comment: @Richard the D was destroyed before its expected end service date, so they had to act fast and give this un named but still capital ship the E tag, (current US navy has a new super carrier enterprise scheduled to be built in the next couple years to coincide with the retirement of the current enterprise) i believe the enterprise D had a an almost 50 year service expectancy, including upgrades and retro fits.

Comment: I read the questions as "replacement hips", and was momentarily confused.

Comment: @JohnWinkelman The Federation supplies those too, they've got *excellent* health care.

Comment: It's not unheard of in real world navies to give a captain a new ship if theirs was lost in battle or by accident given: 1-Another ship is available for them and 2-They were not negligent in any way in the loss of the first ship.

Comment: @BBlake The only odd thing in these shows is that all these new ships have the same name. Most captains don't serve in the same named ships their entire careers, but these all do.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Only the enterprise has continuous service, and replacements. This is mostly due to the long history of use of the name enterprise for earth vessels prior to starfleet. (however star trek has helped increase the number of earth vessels we currently call enterprise). As to why those specific captains receive new enterprises i think we can chalk it up to them being the best captains of the fleet, which is understandable since they are flying the flag ship of the entire federation. Plus the destruction of their ships is always under extreme circumstances. As to captains being given any ship after destroying one, as long as the ships destruction wasn't negligence by the captain their is no reason why they should not receive another ship . you have someone with at least 8 years, if not 10-20 years starfleet experience at the helm of most star fleet ships, its a waste of training to essentially can, and not give these captains replacement ships.

Comment: Right. And not just the captain - the entire Enterprise crew in ST: TNG is considered the creme de la creme of Star Fleet, whose talent would be diluted if reassigned to different ships.